# Combining yew with copper or bronze

Tags: technique

Does combining yew with copper or bronze cause any particular reaction, like tannic acid timber would react, I would like to know this before testing it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is no, but I can't find anything on it and Yew is one wood I am very unfamiliar with, so no answer, just a comment.

Comment: Was this supposed to be combining or combing? Combing made sense to me if you were trying to change the wood on purpose? Combining if you were talking about attaching copper to yew.

Comment: It's not enough for it's own question i think, but is there a list of woods and their reaction to different materials? (i.e.: adding a copper inlay to a larch gift-box)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the copper or bronze but i think it would need sealing when finished to stop it turning green unless that is the effect you want. You can use fine metal powders and set with superglue or resin. I can post a link to something I filled with aluminum powder if allowed ?

Iron can have an effect and give shades of purple, iv seen this around nails or wire but that's wood grown around it.